# flight reservation schema : no card in google now

Tags: google-schemas, google-now

Using google sccript + my own gmail account , I am sending a flight reservation schema ( microdata format ).

The corresponding weather forecast cards (departure/arrival)  are poping up on google now, but so far, no boarding pass has been shown.
Any idéal why ?

Please note I did not include any action as I understand those are not supported yet.

Here is the templace I have used.

Basically it is almost the same as in the google example, except I have changed date and location just in case google now would be based on those.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/FlightReservation">
    <meta itemprop="reservationNumber" content="RXJ34P"/>

    <div itemprop="underName" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Renaud Huillet"/>
    </div>

    <div itemprop="reservationFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Flight">
        <meta itemprop="flightNumber" content="110"/>
        <div itemprop="airline" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airline">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="United"/>
            <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="UA"/>
        </div>

        <div itemprop="departureAirport" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airport">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="Nice Cote d Azur"/>
            <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="NCE"/>
            <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="Nice"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <meta itemprop="departureTime" content="2013-05-27T11:15:00+01:00"/>
        <div itemprop="arrivalAirport" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Airport">
            <meta itemprop="name" content="John F. Kennedy International Airport"/>
            <meta itemprop="iataCode" content="JFK"/>
            <div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="New York"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <meta itemprop="arrivalTime" content="2017-05-27T19:30:00-05:00"/>
    </div>

    <meta itemprop="airplaneSeat" content="9A"/>

    <div itemprop="airplaneSeatClass" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AirplaneSeatClass">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="Business"/>
    </div>

    <meta itemprop="ticketNumber" content="ABC1234"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email markup that you're using is the correct way to send the confirmation email for a flight reservation. However, once the passenger has checked in and a boarding pass has been issued, another email needs to be sent with the [boarding pass information](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/flight-reservation#boarding_pass) in order to trigger a card in Google Now.

As long as the confirmation numbers and passenger details match, the two emails will be merged into one flight reservation with a boarding pass. In order for that boarding pass to show up in Google Now you will need to make sure all the [required properties](https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/reference/flight-reservation#specification) are filled in and provide a URL to a barcode/qrcode image using the ticketToken property. Also make sure that the departureTime is sometime within the next 6 hours or change the time on your device to within 6 hours of the specified departureTime.

Comment: is 6 hours to start/departure/checkin time a hard rule for all Google Now cards?  I have been testing an EventReservation, inbox button works but no GN card.  Thanks.